# Shiro: Cannot invalidate HttpSession

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, shiro, httpsession

I have a Shiro session (id=11111) and a http session (id=22222).

When I try to invalidate the HttpSession, the wrong id is used.

**Code:**

```
public void logout() {
      SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();

// exception is thrown in this line
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException:
 There is no session with id [22222]
```

How can I invalidate the HttpSession or rather set the correct id?

Comment: The complete stack trace would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by implementing a HttpSessionBindingListener and create a mapping of Shiro sessions to http sessions.

Answer (score 0):

SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout() stop and invalidate the session from DefaultSecurityManager.logout(Subject subject). So the session could not be invalidated after logout() call.